# How do I speed up my RBF kernel function in my k-means algorithm

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, matrix, k-means

I am tring to implement the RBF Kernel Function for my kernel k-means alg. Here is my formula.
[image]
[image]
And then I implement it with Numpy, but there's a two-layer for loop, and I'm thinking about how to turn it into a matrix operation. Because if I could do matrix operations, it would be a lot faster to process my 784-dimensional data. Or maybe my implemention is not correct? Can someone help me?

```py
import numpy as np

def get_gamma(X, Y):
    gamma = 0
    for x in X:
        for y in Y:
            tmp = x - y
            gamma += tmp**2
    gamma = gamma / (length**2)
    return gamma

def kernel(X, Y, gamma):
    up = np.sum(np.power(X-Y, 2))
    res = np.exp(-*up/gamma)
    return res

def kernel_distance(X, Y):
    gamma = get_gamma(X, Y)
    a = kernel(X, X, gamma)
    b = kernel(Y, Y, gamma)
    c = kernel(X, Y, gamma)
    return np.sqrt(a+b-2*c)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's odd if I run your code it gives me a number for k. But shouldn't it be an array? Also shouldn't `X` and `Y` be 2d since those are basically a list of your points? Anyways if I take my own `X` and `Y`

```
from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist
import numpy as np

n = 10
X = np.random.random((n,3))
Y = np.random.random((n,3))
```

I can solve your problem like this

```
norms_sq = cdist(X,Y,'sqeuclidean')
two_sigma_sq = 1/n**2*np.sum(norms_sq)
k = np.exp(-norms_sq/two_sigma_sq)
```

Comment: In fact, I want to change the Euclidean distance formula in kernel K Means algorithm to the kernel method. So X and Y are all n-dimension vectors, the result i can get will be a scalar.

Comment: @jack Are you sure about that? It is both usually the case and indicated in your formula that X is a n by d matrix where d is the number of dimensions of your data points and n is the amount of data points. I.e. X is what you get when you stack all your points. Then the kernel is a n by n or n by m matrix where the i,j-th element holds the distance between i-th and j-th vector.

Comment: Yes, I confirm. The distance between two points should be a scalar even by using the rbf kernel function.

Comment: @jack usually libraries that work with kernels e.g. scikit-learn expect the kernel in the form I described and that also resembles your formula above. It is scalar for two inputs but is precomputed for all combinations of potions therefore you get a matrix.

Comment: I know what you mean, but I just want the Kmeans algorithm to apply the RBF kernel function when calculating the distance between the sample point and the cluster center point. And the distance between the two points should be a number